# Insert html code in Android sqlite database

Tags: android, html, sqlite

I need a little help with an sqlite issue that I have.I'm trying to save json data which i get from the server and I get an exception trying to insert html code into the sqlite database.Here is the code I am usig for it and the exception :

CODE:

```
public boolean executeInsert() {
        UserDatabaseHelper userDbHelper = new UserDatabaseHelper(context, null, 1);
        userDbHelper.initialize(context);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        try {
            values.put("objectId", objectId);
            values.put("objectOid", objectOid);

            String jsonData = new String(contentBuffer,"UTF-8");
            Log.w("JSONDATA","JSONDATA VALID OR NOT : "+jsonData);
            json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONObject jsonObj =(JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonData).nextValue();
            locale = jsonObj.getString("locale");
            Log.w("LOCALE","SHOW LOCALE  : "+locale);

            contentType = Integer.parseInt(jsonObj.getString("content_type"));
            Log.w("CONTENT TYPE","SHOW CONTENT TYPE : "+contentType);
                values.put("contentType", contentType);

            format = Integer.parseInt(jsonObj.getString("format"));
            Log.w("FORMAT","SHOW FORMAT : "+format);
                values.put("format", format);

            title = jsonObj.getString("title");
            Log.w("TITLE","SHOW TITLE : "+title);
                values.put("title", title);

            content = jsonObj.getString("content");
            Log.w("CONTENT","SHOW CONTENT : "+content);
                values.put("content", content);

            lastUpdate = jsonObj.getString("last_updated");
            Log.w("LAST UPDATED","LAST UPDATED : "+lastUpdate);
                values.put("dateUpdated", lastUpdate);

            collectionId = jsonObj.optInt("collection_id", 0);
                values.put("collectionId", collectionId);
            cardId = jsonObj.optInt("card_id", 0);
                values.put("cardId", cardId);

            userDbHelper.executeQuery("content", values);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w("Error","FUCKKKKKKKKKKKKKK ERROR : "+e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w("Error","FUCKKKKKKKKKKKKKK ERROR : "+e);
        }
        return true;

    }
```

EXCEPTION:

```
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): Error inserting content=Welcome to Stampii<br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): <br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): Your favourite collections synchronised on your computer and your mobile in a new format: stampii Download them with photos, and constantly updated statistics. Swap and play with your friends and enjoy their contents even when you're offline!<br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): <br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): From theArea in the Kiosk, you'll be able to browse through all tha active collections, and find the one that you like best.<br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): <br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): Once you've selected the choosed collection, you just have to activate it to start enjoying your. You can make as many collections as you want at the same time.<br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): <br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): You can purchase yourfrom theStore, via sms or promotional vouchers.<br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): <br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): Allfollow a similar structure. They're all represented with a portrait with an image and all the data referred to the character that you've got in your.<br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): <br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): Your collection will be updated for free with the last info every time you select the sincronize button. Yourconstantly updated.<br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): <br />
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): Enjoy searching, negotiating and changing your repeated stampii with your friends, use your mobile and the social networks to get the you were looking for. title=Title Tutorial format=2 contentType=1 objectId=1 dateUpdated=2010-03-26 16:56:43
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1623)
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1484)
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862):     at com.stampii.stampii.comm.rpc.UserDatabaseHelper.execQuery(UserDatabaseHelper.java:252)
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862):     at com.stampii.stampii.comm.rpc.UserDatabaseHelper.executeQuery(UserDatabaseHelper.java:247)
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862):     at com.stampii.stampii.comm.rpc.ContentRPCPacket.executeBefore(ContentRPCPacket.java:105)
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862):     at com.stampii.stampii.user.UserLogin$2$1.run(UserLogin.java:365)
09-27 08:48:52.279: ERROR/Database(7862):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
```

**EDIT**

Here is my function about which I am using for inserting data in SQLite :

```
public boolean executeQuery(String tableName,ContentValues values){
    return execQuery(tableName,values);
}

private  boolean execQuery(String tableName,ContentValues values){
    sqliteDb = instance.getWritableDatabase();
    sqliteDb.insert(tableName, null, values);
    return true;
}
```

I am using this method like this :

```
userDbHelper.executeQuery("content", values);//content is the name of my table
//userDBHelper is an instance of my DatabaseHelper class.
```

And what type of data I have on my table :

1. id (integer)
2. objectId (integer)
3. format (integer)
4. contentType (integer)
5. dateUpdated (varchar)
6. content (Text)
7. objectOid (varchar)

Any ideas how to fix that so I can save the html code in sqlite?

Comment: Its not an issue of HTML tags. It says constraint failed. Check the limit of the field and other constraints that you have provided to the field of table. If still its shows issue. Please provide your table schema.

Comment: sqllite is a relational database management system. Your example has no SQL in it, so doesn't show us anything about how your interacting with the database. We're not going to be able to help until you show a more complete code snippet - what does you database schema look like? What is the insert statement you're trying to execute? From the error message it looks as though you may be executing that text as SQL statements, which clearly isn't going to work...

Comment: I just update my question,with more information about my code.

Comment: Apologies. Just realised Android exposes those helper methods, so you're not actually writing the insert statements yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Try to simplify your code until you get it working. Firstly, replace the line:

```
content = jsonObj.getString("content");
```

With the line:

```
content = "somethingsimple";
```

If that works, then you know it's something about the content string.

Do you know the max size of that column?

Comment: Actually I'm inserting all the values,but only content is crashing.You can see all inserts here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561006/android-sqliteconstraintexception-issue

Comment: Why have you posted the same question twice?

Comment: So, can you help me with that or not, because I searched all over internet and nothings helped me....

Comment: Your duplicate question is now gone, so we still don't know what the other values are you're inserting and we don't know what your schema looks like. If you add those I may be able to spot something.

Comment: I just update my question with the code and what type of data I have in my database.Actually the only exception I get is with content.If you have any suggestions I will be really glad to hear them, and if you need any more information just ask...and thanks for helping me I really appreciate that.